# python splitting and re-combining strings of a list

Tags: python, string, list, data-structures

I have a pair of elements as a sub-list in my Python list of lists. The full list looks like this:

```
L = [
      ["ImoduleB.pinN_in", "ImoduleC.pinO_out"], 
      ["ImoduleA.pinM_in", "ImoduleB.pinN_out"],
      ["ImoduleC.pinO_in", "ImoduleD.pinP_out"]
]
```

Where `ImoduleA, ImoduleB, ImoduleC, ImoduleD` are my instance names and `pinM_*, pinN_*, pinO_*, pinP_*` are the pin names.

I am interested to isolate the instance names for further processing, and I plan to attach the pin names back to their instances after processing is done.

```
L_instances = [
      ["ImoduleB", "ImoduleC"], 
      ["ImoduleA", "ImoduleB"],
      ["ImoduleC", "ImoduleD"]
]

L_pins = [
      ["pinN_in", "pinO_out"], 
      ["pinM_in", "pinN_out"],
      ["pinO_in", "pinP_out"]
]
```

One **important** thing to note is ... Elements in `L_instances` will get re-ordered during processing. One simple example is:

```
L_instances_processed = [
      ["ImoduleA", "ImoduleB"], # re-ordered
      ["ImoduleB", "ImoduleC"], # re-ordered
      ["ImoduleC", "ImoduleD"]
]
```

**Questions is**: How do I combine the re-ordered instances and their pins back together into their original string? Should I store the sub-list into a dictionary instead? No processing is done on the pins.

```
 L_combined = [
      ["ImoduleA.pinM_in", "ImoduleB.pinN_out"], 
      ["ImoduleB.pinN_in", "ImoduleC.pinO_out"],
      ["ImoduleC.pinO_in", "ImoduleD.pinP_out"]
]
```

If there is a better way to split and recombine them, please feel free to throw in your solutions.

Comment: then go for dict

Comment: mind to show us how?

Comment: does the order in `L` list matter?

Comment: The order in the `L` list will get re-arranged after processing

Answer (score 0):

You can try with dictionary then :

```
L = [
  ["ImoduleB.pinN_in", "ImoduleC.pinO_out"],
  ["ImoduleA.pinM_in", "ImoduleB.pinN_out"],
  ["ImoduleC.pinO_in", "ImoduleD.pinP_out"]
]

k = []
for i in L:
    d = {}
    for j in i:
        s = j.split(".")
        d.update({s[0]:s[1]})
    k.append(d)
print(k)
```

Output :

```
[{'ImoduleB': 'pinN_in', 'ImoduleC': 'pinO_out'}, 
 {'ImoduleA': 'pinM_in', 'ImoduleB': 'pinN_out'}, 
 {'ImoduleC': 'pinO_in', 'ImoduleD': 'pinP_out'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [
      ["ImoduleB.pinN_in", "ImoduleC.pinO_out"], 
      ["ImoduleA.pinM_in", "ImoduleB.pinN_out"],
      ["ImoduleC.pinO_in", "ImoduleD.pinP_out"]
] 
# split every item 
L_instances = [[i.split('.')[0] for i in x ]for x in L]
# [['ImoduleB', 'ImoduleC'], ['ImoduleA', 'ImoduleB'], ['ImoduleC', 'ImoduleD']]
L_pins= [[i.split('.')[1] for i in x ]for x in L]
# [['pinN_in', 'pinO_out'], ['pinM_in', 'pinN_out'], ['pinO_in', 'pinP_out']]
```

Comment: how do I combine back the split elements?

Comment: @JonJ `[[L_instances[i][0]+'.' +L_pins[i][0], L_instances[i][1]+'.' +L_pins[i][1]] for i in range(len(L_instances))]`

Comment: The order in the `L` will get re-arranged after processing, which means the wrong pins will get combined back to the wrong instances

Comment: @JonJ Post your example then I can check the problem

Comment: I have re-edited the original question for better clarity

Comment: @JonJ, but why do you think `L_instances` is sorted in order, it has the same order like `L` at least in my way.